# how to get a filepath of a xml file in java

Tags: java, xml, filepath

i have a xml file and i want to get the direct path of the file and convert it into String there is any way to do that? 
i tried to compile the code below but it found the wrong file.

```
  File temp = File.createTempFile("staff",".xml" );
          String absolutePath = temp.getAbsolutePath();
                String filePath = absolutePath.
                 substring(0,absolutePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
```

thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "it found the wrong file"? show what it found and what you were expecting.

Comment: it found staff2542556340524684763.xml instead of staff.xml
and i know where the file is but i need the program to find the path itself. if there is any way to do that i would like to get it.

Comment: you are creating a temporary file. the argument you pass is not the file name but the prefix. it is used to generate the name. so you are getting the file that you are creating. see the api http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29